# Spring - maybe AOP? - Figure out who is creating a proxy around my service class

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am a bit lost in spring autoconfig magic.

I see this exception:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entryService'; 
nested exception is 
[...].BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: 
Bean named 'entryService' is expected to be of type 
'[...].EntryService' 
but was actually of type 
'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84'
```

that bean's class is:

```
package ... 

@Service
public class EntryService {

    // several methods, but no further annotations

}
```

I am not sure why spring seems to think I want a proxy around my service? What are my options for debugging this? I suspect that it might be caused by AOP autoproxying, and I do have AOP and spring-tx on the classpath (pulled in through spring-webmvc -> spring-aop and spring-jdbc -> spring-tx).

EDIT =====

turning up logging for spring resulted in this:

```
2018-03-23 11:50:22.421 DEBUG 15483 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2018-03-23 11:50:22.425 DEBUG 15483 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy     : Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [....EntryService@51dae791]
```

EDIT 2 =====

entry service in full:

```
@Service
public class EntryService extends AbstractGuidEntityService<Entry> {

    @Override
    public Entry get(String guid) {
        ....
    } 
}
```

but no other spring specific annotations anywhere up the tree.

Comment: Does `EntryService` implements any interface or the definition posted is complete?

Comment: definition is not complete as is. i added some more info.

Comment: i use the same pattern (and the same superclass) in other projects without seeing spring trying to create proxies.

Comment: Does anywhere in your code you trying to inject `EntryService` as is (e.g. `@Autowired private EntityService entityService`) or via any of the interface (e.g. `@Autowired private SomeInterfaceImplementedByEntityService entityService`) ?

Comment: i did have the concrete class autowired. now i created an interface and autowire the interface instead. it works now. the thing is, i have other services that are structured identically, and they work even without an interface declared.

Comment: great, so my suspicion was correct it was indeed issue with the interface. JDK proxy works for interface and not classes (for which you need to look for CGLIB proxy instead)

Comment: Regarding the other services there must be some interface up their hierarchy which prevents from this issue to occur.

Comment: hmm. i checked the object i get autowired, and they are not proxies. the point is that i don't understand why AOP kicks in at all. there is no @Transactional, nor is there anything else that immediately screams "proxy me" ...